# How to generate multi-page PDF from several html templates?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to generate pdf file from several html strings, each of them placed on the separate page of the document. I wrote the following method:

```
public Optional<File> generatePdf(String[] htmlPages) {
    try {
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider();
        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont();
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
        properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
        File pdfFile = File.createTempFile("pdfdata", null);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfFile);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
        for(int page = 0; page < htmlPages.length; page++) {
            String htmlPage = htmlPages[page];
            File pageFile = File.createTempFile("pagepdfdata", null);
            PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pageFile));
            temp.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(795, 1042));
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlPage, temp, properties);
            temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pageFile)));
            merger.merge(temp, 1, temp.getNumberOfPages());
            pageFile.deleteOnExit();
            temp.close();
        }
        pdfFile.deleteOnExit();
        return Optional.of(pdfFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

However, although pdf file for each page is created correctly, the resulting pdf file has 0 byte length and can not be opened. Could you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'd guesstimate that you need to `close()` your `PdfWriter` to ensure it did all the necessary writing to disk.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for reply, unfortunately this did not help. However, I found another way (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this only by rewriting the code in the following way:

```
public byte[] generatePdf(List<String> htmlPages) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(arrayOutputStream);
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider();
        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont();
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
        properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
        List<PdfDocument> docs = new ArrayList<>();
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        for(String htmlPage: htmlPages) {
            File pageFile = File.createTempFile("pagepdfdata", null);
            PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pageFile));
            temp.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(795, 1042));
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlPage, temp, properties);
            temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pageFile)));
            temp.copyPagesTo(1, temp.getNumberOfPages(), pdf);

            pageFile.deleteOnExit();
            docs.add(temp);
        }
        docs.forEach(PdfDocument::close);
        pdf.close();
        return arrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```